# Android edittext insert html a

Tags: android

I need to insert

`Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"www.google.com\">My site</a>");`

at a position in my edittext. The problem is the edittext doesn't have insert only for CharSequence. I am now using setText method but if the text is very long it needs to redraw all the text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Spanned` implements `CharSequence` so if I call `insert(pos, Html.fromHtml())` works great rather than using : `setText(Html.fromHtml(textBeforePosition + <a href=...>..</a> + textAfterPosition));`

Answer (score 1):

[Call `getText()` on the `EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29) to retrieve the `Editable`, then [call `insert()` on the `Editable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html#insert%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) to insert your `CharSequence`. It is possible that you will need to call `invalidate()` on the `EditText` afterwards to get it to repaint after this change, as I do not know if that will happen automatically.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that isn't my problem. The insert method calls invalidate automatically. The method expects CharSequence, but I need to insert a Spanned returned from Html.fromHtml(). I've later found the solution : Spanned implements CharSequence so if I call insert(pos, Html.fromHtml()) works great rather than using : setText(Html.fromHtml(textBeforePosition + <a href=...>..</a> + textAfterPosition));